# css: two div's in one row, height=100% for smaller one not working

Tags: html, css, height, zurb-foundation

I'm using "foundation for sites" to achieve responsiveness.

There, I have:

```
<div class="row"> <!-- defines a grid of 12 columns -->
  <div class="columns large-1 medium-1">&nbsp;</div> <!-- some space to the left -->
  <div class="columns large-6 medium-6" style="border: red solid 1px;">
    a lot of content, including a header, and multiple lines of text
  </div>  
  <div class="columns large-4 medium-4" style="border: red solid 1px; height: 100%;">
    a little bit of content
  </div>
  <-- the right spacer column is not needed -->  
</div>
```

The red borders are only there for testing. To my understanding, the "height: 100%" of the smaller div should make it as high as the bigger one. But the border is only around the text content. When I inspect the div's using the browser development tools, the "row" div and the big "columns" div have a computed height of >100 px, while the small "column" div has only 17 px.

The reason why I need the 100% height is that the content of the small div will be aligned to the bottom eventually. But before I can do that, the height must work.

The css for classes "row" and "columns" is completely defined in foundation, I did not change or override anything except the element styles in the above example.

What am I missing ?

**Edit:**
I'm trying to paint it in character graphics, showing only the borders of the "columns" div's.

It actually looks like:

```
|--------------------|--------------------|   
| lots of text       | a little text      |  
| lots of text       |--------------------|  
| lots of text       |  
| lots of text       |  
|--------------------|
```

But it should look like:

```
|--------------------|--------------------|  
| lots of text       | a little text      |  
| lots of text       |                    |  
| lots of text       |                    |  
| lots of text       |                    |  
|--------------------|--------------------|
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? It is not vey clear in your question.

Comment: @Paulie_D this *is* the shortest code (besides the comments).

Comment: @Crimp I want to achieve that the smaller "columns" div is as high as the larger one.

Comment: You need to create a demo *including* the CSS.

Comment: I've left the css out because I'm using the original css that comes with "zurb foundation for sites". I also think that for the "height: 100%" problem it does not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I managed to get equal height by using foundation's data-equalizer: https://get.foundation/sites/docs/equalizer.html
As I was using foundation in this webapp already, this was a perfect match.

I still consider myself a relative foundation newbie, so at first I did not know what to search for in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```css
.row{
  display: flex;
}
.columns{
  border: red solid 2px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row"> <!-- defines a grid of 12 columns -->
  <div class="columns large-1 medium-1">&nbsp;</div> <!-- some space to the left -->
  <div class="columns large-6 medium-6" id='large-div'>
    <h2>Header 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div> 
  <div class="columns large-4 medium-4" id='small-div'>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit 
    </p>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: This JavaScript approach worked. Thank you very much. The smaller div has 2 pixels less height than the bigger one this way, but when I remove the borders (that were there for testing only), nobody will notice.  
However ... I'd still love to understand why the height: 100% I had on the smaller div initially hdid not work.